# Apex Batch Job Chaining Limits

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

What is the stack depth for apex batch job chaining? I am conditionally calling the same batch job from the finish method..
Also the solution implemented calls a normal batch job from the finish method and we are not leveraging Queueable Apex.
What will be the daisy chaining limits for the above pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A job may only spawn one other job in the finish method. You would need to design your job to work within this limit, so you might need a different design. There's no limit to the number of times a batch may chain (the stack depth you referred to), although there is a daily execution limit for asynchronous code (see the docs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am just spawning one job from the finish method.  So it seems there are no limits to the chain length.

Comment: Correct. Aside from daily governor limits, no other limitations.